# How to insert rows from one table into another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two following MySQL tables

Table A

```
id Name Age
1  John 25
2  Tony 30
3  Tom  35
```

- Primary Key: id, id is auto increment

Table B

```
id Name Age
1  Sue 25
2  Jane 30
3  Jessica 35
```

- Primary Key: id, id is auto increment

If I want to insert all table B rows into table A, how can I do it? I tried use following query

```
insert into table A select Name, Age from Table B
```

the result is error. This is because the columns do not match. But I cannot include the id column, since it will conflict the id in Table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the columns you are inserting:

```
insert into table A (Name, Age) 
select Name, Age 
from Table B
```